# UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, memory-leaks

I am trying to get rid of the error `[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block` however I fail to fix it despite all of my attept.

Here is the full error message:

```
S C:\Users\vince\project\reverse-engineering\north-korea> node .
(node:13600) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [procet
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13600) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [prot
(node:13600) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 uncaughtException listeners adt
progress [----------------------------------------] 0% | ETA: 0s | 1/10141
progress [----------------------------------------] 0% | ETA: 85s | 90/10141node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,{
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import nmap from "node-nmap";
import log from "fancy-log"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import prog from "cli-progress"

/**
 * Scan for open ports and os
 * @param {string} ip Scan for an IP
 */
async function scanIP(ip) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const scan = new nmap.QuickScan(ip);
    scan.startScan();
    let completeListner, finishListenr;
    completeListner = scan.once("complete", () => {
      scan.removeAllListeners("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete");
      if (scan.scanResults.hostName == null || scan.scanResults.openPorts == null)
        reject();
      resolve(scan.scanResults)
    });

    finishListenr = scan.on("error", (e) => { scan.removeAllListeners("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete"); scan.cancelScan(); reject(e); });
  })

}

const ips_file = fs.readFileSync("./nk-ip.txt", { encoding: "utf8" }).split("\n");
const progBar = new prog.MultiBar({
  // etaAsynchronousUpdate: fals,

 }, prog.Presets.legacy)
const initating = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
const finishedScan = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
let i = 0;
for (const ip of ips_file) {
  scanIP(ip).then(async (open_port) => {
    if (open_port.openPorts == null)
      return; 
    const curr_ip = ip;
    const ip_db = "./open-port.json";
encoding: "utf-8" }));
      openPortsJSON.push(...open_port);
      writeFile(ip_db, JSON.stringify(openPortsJSON), { encoding: "utf-8" }).catch()
      
      
    }).finally(() => { finishedScan.increment({ msg: "Finished scan for IP " + ip}) });
    initating.update({ task: "Scheduled scan for ip " + ip});
  
  i++;
  if (i > 100)
    break;
}

initating.stop();
```

I tried to getting rid of the error by wrapping the main code into a try catch block however I still have the same error.

```js
import fs from "fs";
import nmap from "node-nmap";
import log from "fancy-log"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import prog from "cli-progress"

/**
 * Scan for open ports and os
 * @param {string} ip Scan for an IP
 */
async function scanIP(ip) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const scan = new nmap.QuickScan(ip);
    scan.startScan();
    let completeListner, finishListenr;
    completeListner = scan.once("complete", () => {
      scan.removeAllListeners("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete");
      if (scan.scanResults.hostName == null || scan.scanResults.openPorts == null)
        reject();
      resolve(scan.scanResults)
    });

    finishListenr = scan.on("error", (e) => { scan.removeAllListeners("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete"); scan.cancelScan(); reject(e); });
    scan.initializeChildProcess();
  })

}

const ips_file = fs.readFileSync("./nk-ip.txt", { encoding: "utf8" }).split("\n");
const progBar = new prog.MultiBar({
  // etaAsynchronousUpdate: fals,

 }, prog.Presets.legacy)
const initating = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
const finishedScan = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
let i = 0;
for (const ip of ips_file) {
  scanIP(ip).then(async (open_port) => {
    if (open_port.openPorts == null)
      return; 
    const curr_ip = ip;
    const ip_db = "./open-port.json";
    try {

      const openPortsJSON = JSON.parse(await readFile(ip_db, { encoding: "utf-8" }));
      openPortsJSON.push(...open_port);
      writeFile(ip_db, JSON.stringify(openPortsJSON), { encoding: "utf-8" }).catch()
      
      
    } catch {}
    }).finally(() => { finishedScan.increment({ msg: "Finished scan for IP " + ip}) });
    initating.update({ task: "Scheduled scan for ip " + ip});
  
  i++;
  if (i > 100)
    break;
}

initating.stop();
```

---

Another thing I tried was to wrap the `scanIP(ip)` function  into a try catch block. Node gave me a different error:

```js
(node:4676) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [procest(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4676) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [proct(node:4676) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 uncaughtException listeners addtprogress [----------------------------------------] 0% | ETA: 0s | 1/10141
progress [----------------------------------------] 0% | ETA: 69s | 11/10141

node:events:360
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('Over scan timeout 0')
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at QuickScan.emit (node:events:358:17)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vince\node_modules\node-nmap\index.js:196:14)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
  context: 'Over scan timeout 0'
}
```

Here is how look the attempt:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import nmap from "node-nmap";
import log from "fancy-log"
import { readFile, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import prog from "cli-progress"

/**
 * Scan for open ports and os
 * @param {string} ip Scan for an IP
 */
async function scanIP(ip) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const scan = new nmap.QuickScan(ip);
    scan.startScan();
    let completeListner, finishListenr;
    completeListner = scan.once("complete", () => {
      try {

        scan.removeListener("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete");
        if (scan.scanResults.hostName == null || scan.scanResults.openPorts == null)
        reject();
        resolve(scan.scanResults)
      } catch { }
    });

    finishListenr = scan.on("error", (e) => { try { scan.removeAllListeners("error"); scan.removeAllListeners("complete"); scan.cancelScan(); reject(e); } catch { }; } );
    scan.initializeChildProcess();
  })

}

const ips_file = fs.readFileSync("./nk-ip.txt", { encoding: "utf8" }).split("\n");
const progBar = new prog.MultiBar({
  // etaAsynchronousUpdate: fals,

 }, prog.Presets.legacy)
const initating = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
const finishedScan = progBar.create(ips_file.length, 1);
let i = 0;
for (const ip of ips_file) {
  scanIP(ip).then(async (open_port) => {
    if (open_port.openPorts == null)
      return; 
    const curr_ip = ip;
    const ip_db = "./open-port.json";
    try {

      const openPortsJSON = JSON.parse(await readFile(ip_db, { encoding: "utf-8" }));
      openPortsJSON.push(...open_port);
      writeFile(ip_db, JSON.stringify(openPortsJSON), { encoding: "utf-8" }).catch()
      
      
    } catch {}
    }).finally(() => { finishedScan.increment({ msg: "Finished scan for IP " + ip}) });
    initating.update({ task: "Scheduled scan for ip " + ip});
  
  i++;
  if (i > 100)
    break;
}

initating.stop();
```

Comment: How would I create a good minimal reproductable for this question? I have no idea how I would do it for this issue that I am having

Comment: when you are chaining then add a catch before finally .```scanIp().then(()=>{//code}).catch(console.log).finally(//code);```